# executing raw sql in django error: relation does not exist

Tags: python, sql, django, relational-database, rawsql

I am attempting to execute a raw sql query and I am getting the following error:

```
relation "venue" does not exist
```

the query is as follows:

```
 cityList = Venue.objects.raw("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM Venue")
```

the model I am grabbing from looks like this:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=imgUnique('venueMedia/venueImages'))
streetAddress= models.CharField(max_length=100)
city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

This is a syntax error, and I am having a hard time finding the right documentation regarding the proper syntax. There seems to be alot on curser queries but I am not ready to give up on this yet

Comment: What app is your venue model in? According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries), the table name uses the app name and the model class name, so most likely, your table would be `myapp_venue`, where myapp is the name of your app.

Comment: right, I tried that too with no result. observe the app is called suitsandtables   so i tried it like so suitsandtables_venue with the same error I presented just with suitsandtables_venue. I will update my post with the proof

Comment: wait never mind I made progress! I was thinking of the project name which is suits and tables not the app name which is also venue. I put Select Distinct city From venue_venue and it worked... well to give me a new error which is `Raw query must include the primary key` which is frustrating because it shouldn't need that. But at least now I am on the right track

Comment: Ah, if you're intending to not use the primary key, you can use SQL directory with a connection cursor: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly). However, I would use the suggested method of [QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects). In your case, it's as simple as doing `all_venues = Venue.objects.all()`, then iterating through `all_venues` to create a city set.

Comment: Why are you using raw SQL at all here? This query is easily expressed in the ORM: `Venue.objects.values_list('city').distinct()`.

Comment: thats ultimately what I used. But I do prefer raw sql, as I enjoy writing sql statements and I gotta use something from my CS degree lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the raw SQL. The Django ORM can do this like.

> citylist = Venue.objects.values('city').distinct()

Doku [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).